# Getting an exception when tried to implement Azure AD authentication and authorization in Spring Boot

Tags: java, azure, spring-mvc, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I receive the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration$OAuth2WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.security.oauth2.client-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientProperties': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client id must not be empty.
```

Even though I've provided the client ID in `application.properties`.

I followed the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory

POM:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.mmm</groupId>
<artifactId>UserMgmt</artifactId>
<version>1.0.3</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>UserMgmt</name>
<description>User Management</description>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<!-- <url>http://www.example.com</url> -->
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.956</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.207</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>     
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>     
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>     
        <version>2.8.6</version>     
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>
<build> 
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
        
    
    <pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.9.Final</version>
                </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

MAIN:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
private static final Logger LOG = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserApplication.class.getName());


public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);

}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
application) {
return application.sources(UserApplication.class);
}

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {/*creds*/}
```

CONTROLLER

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_group1')"+"|| hasRole('ROLE_group2')"+"|| 
hasRole('ROLE_group3')")
```

APPLICATION.PROPERTIES

```
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
azure.activedirectory.client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
azure.activedirectory.client-secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
azure.activedirectory.user-group.allowed-groups=group1,group2,group3
```

I updated my POM with

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

The new error after updating POM:

```
 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication [main] Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.azure.spring.aad.webapp.AADWebAppConfiguration$DefaultAADWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuthorizedClientRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientRepository' defined in class path resource [com/azure/spring/aad/webapp/AADWebAppConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository]: Factory method 'authorizedClientRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider
```

I've updated my POM, now it is building fine, but on login I'm getting AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '18da6914-............................'. I added the following redirect URI: `localhost:8080`, `localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code`.

As I'm completely new to this, I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Can you add code  ?

Comment: Have you checked your `application.properties`? And remember add @EnableWebSecurity and @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) in your application class.

Comment: @VovaBilyachat , thanx for response , i 've shared some code

Comment: @PamelaPeng, thanx for response , i have added those as well

Comment: @PamelaPeng i've updated pom even checked application.properties now i'm getting different error

Comment: @PamelaPeng, thanx for response. I've updated my pom , now it is building fine . But on login i'm getting AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '18da6914-............................' added following redirect uri localhost:8080 localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code

Comment: As the error says, the `RedirectUri` in the code needs to be the same as Redirect URI in the portal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jRXy.png

Comment: The sample uses `http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/` as redirect uri, try to change with it.

Comment: Hi, @shubhamyadav. If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct. But as the error shows *"nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client id must not be empty."*, you need to check the application.properties again and make sure it's correct.

And the sample needs three dependencies(`spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`, `spring-boot-starter-web`, `azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory`), you could try to update your pom with the newer version.

There is my code following the tutorial.

**Main:**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootSampleAdApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSampleAdApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
    application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootSampleAdApplication.class);
    }

    @Configuration
    public class DataSourceConfiguration {/*creds*/}
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_pamela-group1')"+"|| hasRole('ROLE_pamela-group2')")
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello Users!";
    }
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=xxxxx
azure.activedirectory.client-id=xxxxx
azure.activedirectory.client-secret=xxxxx
azure.activedirectory.user-group.allowed-groups=pamela-group1,pamela-group2
```

[image: application.properties]

**Test result:**

[image]

Comment: i've updated pom and checked application.properties but getting different error

Comment: jzheaux has answered about NoClassDefFoundError exception. On my side, I follow the tutorial using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the main issue is with your Spring Boot version. You have specified `2.1.6.RELEASE`, but a newer version may be more appropriate.

Here are a couple of observations and I'll follow that with a recommended fix.

You added Spring Security 5.4.x dependencies, however, these are intended for use with Spring Boot 2.4.x.

The tutorial bases itself on Spring Boot 2.3.x. Spring Security's 5.3.x dependencies are intended for use with Spring Boot 2.3.x.

The reason you are getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` is because `AADWebAppConfiguration` is trying to look up a class that isn't introduced until after Spring Boot 2.1.

I think the best thing to do is ensure that your dependencies are aligned with the tutorial that you are following, or that they are the latest dependencies.

Specifically, you have this:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

as well as this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

but they are not compatible with one another.

I'd recommend starting with the Spring Boot version that the tutorial uses in order to get things working.

Comment: thanx for response.I've updated my pom , now it is building fine . But on login i'm getting AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '18da6914-............................'                 added following redirect                                      uri http://localhost:8080
http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/

Comment: For searchability, it's important to keep the scope of a question to a specific issue. I'd recommend a new SO post for your new question.